# Combining two mono and returning value

Tags: java, spring, mono, spring-webflux

I am using 2 Mono and combining them to perform a certain tasks but it is not going inside the flatMap block.

```
public Mono<Invocable> getJSCompiledInstance() {
    return Mono.fromFuture(jsScriptCache.get(SCRIPT_KEY).toCompletableFuture());
}
```

```
private AsyncLoadingCache<String, Invocable> jsScriptCache;
private AsyncLoadingCache<Key, String> ruleSetVersionsCache;
private AsyncLoadingCache<String, String> currentlyLiveSetVersionCache;

public Mono<Object> evaluateVersion(Key key, String facts, boolean showTestResults) {
        System.out.println("Inside Evaluate By Version");
        return getJSCompiledInstance().zipWith(Mono.fromFuture(ruleSetVersionsCache.get(key).toCompletableFuture()))
                .flatMap(tuple -> {
                    String ruleSetVersion = tuple.getT2();
                    Invocable inv = tuple.getT1();

                    if (ruleSetVersion.equals("null")) {
                        return Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Unable to fetch currently live rule set version for" +
                                "for rule set id " + key.getRuleSetId()));
                    }

                    try {
                        JSONObject ruleSetVersionObject = new JSONObject(ruleSetVersion);
                        String ruleSetVersionId = ruleSetVersionObject.get("id").toString();
                        Object result = inv.invokeFunction("evaluate", key.getRuleSetId(), ruleSetVersion, facts, ruleSetVersionId, showTestResults);
                        System.out.println("===================");
                        System.out.println(result);
                        System.out.println("===================");
                        return Mono.just(result);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return Mono.error(new RuntimeException(e.getMessage()));
                    }
                });
    }
```

No println inside the flatMap is getting printed.

Comment: Sorry didn't get you.

Comment: No need to apologize.

Comment: have you actually made sure that the caches actually return something.

Comment: Yes @Toerktumlare cache is returning data

Comment: i doubt it, because if both would return data they would enter the `flatMap` but in your case it doesn't, so one or both must return something `empty`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two calls which can return you an empty result. Try to use `defaultIfEmpty` or `switchIfEmpty` to return default values. Until both of your calls return actual value it wont get into `flatMap`